# Possible to retain edge weights after extracting network backbone?

Tags: r, igraph

I am working with a complex, weighted network of which I would like to extract the statistically significant backbone using the disparity filter in the R package 'backbone.' (https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/backbone/html/disparity.html)

`new_graph <- disparity(g, alpha = alpha)`

The resulting "backbone" graph from the above example outputs a network that is still technically considered weighted (is_weighted = TRUE) however all remaining edges have had their weights flattened to 1. The CRAN page for the disparity function does not appear to have any parameters that allow retention of edge weights.

This makes it impossible to calculate weighted centrality measures or utilize the edge-weights as an input in community detection algorithms from the resulting graph.

I am wondering if there are any alternatives available in R for extracting the backbone of a network in a way that retains the edge-weights of the remaining edges, whether using a disparity filter or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working with the backbone package also and encountered this problem. After some experimentation I think I've come up with the simplest way to do this.

Start with your original weighted igraph object, convert it to a matrix. Feed this into the disparity() function. Then assign weights to the resulting unweighted filtered igraph object using the edge weights in your original graph. You'll need to use as_ids to pull out the edges into a normal R string vector. Then you use %in% to create boolean. You can then use this to index your original igraph object's edge weights.
I wrote a function to do this. See below:

```
filter_graph <- function(graph, alpha = 0.05, narrative = FALSE) {


  # CREATE AN ADJACENCY MATRIX FROM THE IGRAPH OBJECT
  adj_matrix <- as_adjacency_matrix(graph, attr = "Weight", sparse = FALSE)

  # CONVERT THE ADJACENCY MATRIX TO A MATRIX"
  adj_matrix <- as.matrix(adj_matrix)
  # USE THE ADJACENCY MATRIX IN THE DISPARITY() FUNCTION
  result <- disparity(adj_matrix, alpha = alpha, class = "igraph",narrative = narrative)
  # GET VECTOR OF EDGE WEIGHTS FOR EDGES IN FILTERED IGRAPH
  Weights <-  E(graph)$Weight[as_ids(E(graph))  %in% as_ids(E(result))]
  # ADD EDGE WEIGHTS TO IGRAPH OBJECT
  result <- result %>% 
    set_edge_attr("Weight",value = Weights)
  
  return(result)
  
}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, does this eliminate vertex attributes in the "results" graph such that they would have to be reassigned in a similar way as the edge-weights?

Comment: Glad it worked!

Comment: It does remove node attributes also yes. So if you wanted that information, you'll need to reassign it, using the same method as above. Cheers